# Number of ways combination

Tags: combinatorics

By how many dieffernet way can you place $3$ identical balls in $4$ boxes? 
I used  $\binom{n+r-1}n$ =$\binom{6}4=15$ . Is it right?

Comment: You should be able to check this by hand.  First of all, are the boxes distinguishable?  That is, is $\{3,0,0,0\}$ different from $\{0,3,0,0\}$?  Either way, there aren't many cases.

Comment: yes it's 'stars and bars' and the formula is correct - if you want to understand it draw the 3 stars and 4 bars on paper and imagine how swapping the bars around creates different numbers of stars in each box - the bars are the dividers between the boxes (there are 3 gaps between the 4 boxes)

Comment: @AndrewDeighton  I get $\binom 63=20$.  There are $4$ with pattern $\{3,0,0,0\}$.  There are $12$ with pattern $\{2,1,0,0\}$ and there are $4$ with pattern $\{1,1,1,0\}$.

Comment: yes I agree, I got it wrong.

Comment: Assuming the boxes are distinguishable, of course...which the OP needs to specify.

Comment: @Lulu 23 thnx I've get it

Comment: Well...$23$ isn't the right answer.  How did you do your count?

Answer (score 1):

As there is a fair bit of confusion in some of the comments and in the posted solutions, let me write out an answer.  Throughout I will assume that the boxes are distinguishable.

First of all, a direct count:  There are only three ways to write $3$ as the sum of positive integers $3=3,\;3=2+1,\;3=1+1+1$  Each gives us a pattern for your box fills.

$3=3$, for example, gives us $\fbox 4$ solutions:  $\{3,0,0,0\},\;\{0,3,0,0\},\;\{0,0,3,0\},\{0,0,0,3\}$.  A quicker way to count is to simply remark that the solution is determined by specifying which box gets all the balls and there are $4$ choices.

$3=2+1$ gives us $\fbox {12}$.  The pattern is $\{2,1,0,0\}$ and we have $4$ places to put the $2$ and then $3$ places to put the   $1$, and $4\times 3=12$

$3=1+1+1$ gives us $\fbox 4$ as there are $4$ places to put the $0$.

Combining these we get $$4+12+4=\fbox {20}$$

Second method: [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  This is the formula you are trying to use, but mixing up the variables. To be sure, for larger collections a direct count is impractical so it's good to learn the general technique. To do it properly, write the balls as three stars in a line $$\star\star\star$$  We now insert three bars in the spaces between them and on either side, for example $$\star / \star // \star$$  Interpreting the bars as the gaps between the boxes we see that the indicated pattern corresponds to the solution $\{1,1,0,1\}$. Similarly $$//\star\star/\star$$ corresponds to the solution $\{0,0,2,1\}$ and $$\star\star\star///$$ gives us $\{3,0,0,0\}$.

In this way we see that the set of solutions is in bijection with the ways to place the three stars in six slots.  Hence the answer is $$\binom 63=\fbox {20}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you don't permit multiple balls per box then there are 4 ways, since you will simply have one empty box left over and the choice is simply which of the 4 boxes will be the empty one.

If you do permit multiple balls per box then you have 4 ways of arranging {3,0,0,0}, 12 ways of arranging {2,1,0,0}, and 4 ways of arranging {1,1,1,0} as mentioned above.  That gives you the answer of 20.

Answer (score -2):

I refer you to "Number of ways of distributing n identical objects among r groups" also in the Mathematics section of Stack Exchange.  Looks like you are almost there; the answer is {n+r /choose r} = 35 in your case, if I have understood your question properly. (NB The order in which the balls are placed is not accounted for in a combination calculation, so there are quite a few ways of distributing the balls as, *e.g.*, 2 in 1 box and 1 in another here.)

Comment: This answer is not correct.

Comment: Read the entry I suggested, @lulu.  Making a statement without backing it up in any way is not helpful, and not generally the way things are done in SE.

Comment: The answer is obviously not $35$.  Count them by hand.

Comment: There are 3 ways to put 3 identical balls into one box. Bring 4 boxes into the equation and you now have 12 ways, This does not even begin to consider the cases where the balls are split into groups of 2 and 1, or added individually. 

Technically speaking, I agree with the answer given in these pages elsewhere (you have the reference), which is {C(n + r - 1, r - 1)}.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.  What are the three ways to put three identical balls in one box?  The formula in your comment is not the same as the one in your post.  And $\binom {3+4-1}3=20$.

Comment: Well, that at least is apparent!

Comment: Order must be accounted for in combinations, although this is not true when considering permutations.  Either way, I would not try to "think" your way through this problem; it is a lot more complicated than it seems at face value.

Comment: The second formula I gave is the non-simplified version of the first. this time accounting for partitioning.